# Excel VBA For Each Case Send Email

Tags: excel, foreach, outlook, select-case, vba

Hi I am using the below code to send multiple emails based on different cases. (Email addressess and other information are stored in a worksheet) The code works fine however I have 20 different cases (example below only shows two). Putting the outlook application code within each case seems cumbersome.

Is there a method to perform the email against each case without having to express the outlook code within each case?

I have searched using For Each Case without any luck. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub RequestUpdates()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim blRunning As Boolean
Dim email As String
Dim fname As String
Dim fllink As String
Dim cpname As String
Dim v As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rdate As Date
Dim signature As String


v = Sheets("Contributors").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets("Contributors").Range("A1")
rdate = Sheets("Contributors").Range("A1").Value

For y = 0 To v
    Select Case rng.Offset(1 + y, 0).Value

     Case "PCR"
        email = Sheets("Contributors").Range("E4").Value
        fname = Sheets("Contributors").Range("D4").Value
        fllink = Sheets("Contributors").Range("F4").Value
        cpname = Sheets("Contributors").Range("B4").Value

            'get application
            blRunning = True
            Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If olApp Is Nothing Then
            Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
            blRunning = False
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                With olMail
                .Display
                End With
                signature = olMail.HTMLBody
                With olMail
                'Specify the email subject
                .Subject = "test " & rdate
                'Specify who it should be sent to
                'Repeat this line to add further recipients
                .Recipients.Add email
                 'specify the file to attach
                 'repeat this line to add further attachments
                '.Attachments.Add "LinktoAttachment"
                 'specify the text to appear in the email
                .HTMLBody = "<p>Hi " & fname & ",</p>" & _
                "<P>Please follow the link below to update the " & cpname & " test" _
                & "For month ending " & rdate & ".</p>" & _
                "<P> </br> </p>" & _
                fllink & _
                "<P> </br> </p>" & _
                "<p>If you face issues with file access please contact me directly.</p>" & _
                "<P>Note: xxxxx.</p>" & _
                signature
                 'Choose which of the following 2 lines to have commented out
                .Display 'This will display the message for you to check and send yourself
                 '.Send ' This will send the message straight away
                End With

       Case "NFG"

            email = Sheets("Contributors").Range("E6").Value
            fname = Sheets("Contributors").Range("D6").Value
            fllink = Sheets("Contributors").Range("F6").Value
            cpname = Sheets("Contributors").Range("B6").Value

               'get application
            blRunning = True
            Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If olApp Is Nothing Then
            Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
            blRunning = False
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                With olMail
                .Display
                End With
                signature = olMail.HTMLBody
                With olMail
                'Specify the email subject
                .Subject = "Test" & rdate
                'Specify who it should be sent to
                'Repeat this line to add further recipients
                .Recipients.Add email
                 'specify the file to attach
                 'repeat this line to add further attachments
                '.Attachments.Add "LinktoAttachment"
                 'specify the text to appear in the email
                .HTMLBody = "<p>Hi " & fname & ",</p>" & _
                "<P>Please follow the link below to update the " & cpname & " component Test" _
                & "For month ending " & rdate & ".</p>" & _
                "<P> </br> </p>" & _
                fllink & _
                "<P> </br> </p>" & _
                "<p>If you face issues with file access please contact me directly.</p>" & _
                "<P>Note: Test.</p>" & _
                signature
                 'Choose which of the following 2 lines to have commented out
                .Display 'This will display the message for you to check and send yourself
                 '.Send ' This will send the message straight away
                End With
            End Select
            Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two cases you showed follow one template, how about creating sub which sends emails retreiving subject, to etc. from parameters and then calling it from within `Select Case` with proper values passed?